# I have a main method and three classes and I need to compile - eclipse

Tags: java, html, pong

I am using Eclipse and I am making the game pong from a tutorial. I have copied the code of the 4 classes (one main class) into notepads so I can use them how I need too... I have HTML code to use also...

I am using ecplise... how do I get these chunks of code to connect and work? three seperate .java and a .class? or something

please help.

Comment: Create a new Java project, paste in the classes (with correct packages), run the program?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Have a look at [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) in the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). Your question is very general. What have you done? Please be more specific.

Comment: [Follow this link for tutorials on Eclipse](http://www.vogella.com/articles/Eclipse/article.html)

Answer (score 1):

Create a project,add existing files to your project.That's it.

Comment: but I have the 4 classes I need to make... but then the HTML to add somewhere? what package should I use?

Comment: I don't have the files, just what needs to go into them